# Division of a Convex Shape results in a Convex Shape

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $P$ be almost a convex polygon in the plane. By almost, we mean that some edges could be arcs and not just line segments, as long as $P$ remains convex. Let $L$ be a line going through $P$, dividing $P$ into two regions, $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Show that both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are convex.

This problem comes from the idea of dividing a circle by chords, in which case the resulting regions are polygons or polygons with one arc instead of line segment. But I believe in this more general setting, the same proof would hold.

Comment: Basic idea is that this line divides the plane into two half spaces. We can see $P_1$ and $P_2$ as the intersection of $P$ with each half space and then use the fact that if you're in $P$ but not in $P_1$ you must be in the other half space, but this is a contradiction since we can plug the convex combination into the inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally: the intersection of two convex sets is convex.  This is immediate from the definition.

Comment: Yes, this is more elegant than brute forcing the half space inequalities.